# Trying to print out json from a decoded base64 - Python

Tags: python, json, base64

So I have been trying to use base64 to decode a value and then be able to use those decoded strings to print out each for themselves.

Basically my decoded base64 is:

```
{
  "trailerColor": "FF0017",
  "complete": 59,
  "bounds": [
    25,
    65,
    62,
    5
  ],
  "Stamina": 0,
  "cardId": "d4fc5458-3481-4ce6-be32-acd03c2cfd16",
}
```

Im using this code which gets the metadata that I wish and then convert it into a UTF-8 basically with the code below.

```
   resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json=json, timeout=6)

    getmetadata = resp.json()['objects'][1]['metadata']
    newdata = base64.b64decode(getmetadata).decode('UTF-8')

    print(newdata)
```

However usually if I did `newdata['trailerColor']` it should be able to print out only trailerColor if I do that but what i'm getting for error is:

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

How can I solve this by printing whatever I want out through that json?

EDIT:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\TEST.py", line 194, in script
    print(newdata['complete'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: I just added it now @DYZ

Comment: new data is a string, you are accessing it as a dictionary, you have to convert it to a dictionary first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, json=json, timeout=6)

getmetadata = resp.json()['objects'][1]['metadata']
newdata = base64.b64decode(getmetadata).decode('UTF-8')
data = json.loads(newdata)
print(data['complete'])
```

`base64.b64decode(str).decode(str)` returns a string `str`.  If that string should be json then you can use `json.loads` to transform the string `str` to a `dict` where you can get a single value by it's key.

Comment: Oh! There we go! This was the solution! Thanks! :)